# MATLAB on a Docker windows container

Tags: windows, matlab, docker, wcf

We have a some WCF services which we are trying to move to a Docker container. We are using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf` as our base image and have been able to setup the WCF services.

But one of the services use a MATLAB library compiled to run on MCR 8.2 64 bit version. Whenever the service is hit, it generates an exception as

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception. 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception. 
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'mclmcrrt8_2.dll': The specified module could not be found.
```

For the sake of POC, we are manually installing the MCR on the docker container by initiating a powershell session and then then manually updating the **Path** environment variable. We can see in the installation logs that MCR has installed successfully and path variable has also been updated. But the error stills states that it was not able to locate 'mclmcrrt8_2.dll'.

Any ideas on how to get MCR running on docker windows container?

Comment: This sounds like something TMW's support should advise on. [Here's a link](https://www.mathworks.com/support/servicerequests/create.html) to opening a service request.

Comment: How are you manually updating the %PATH% variable? Depending on how you do that, it might not immediately propagate to all contexts, esp. things like Windows Services or things running under Windows Scheduler.

Comment: @AndrewJanke We open a powershell session with the docker container to update the Path (with target set as machine). The service is running as an IIS website which I do restart after updating the environment variable. I too suspect that value is not propagated to the application and can't get my head around it.

Comment: @Dev-iL thanks for the link.... I have opened a case with the support team and hope something good comes out of it. Will surely keep this thread updated with the outcome.

Comment: @DipinBehl: That sounds like it might be your problem. Restarting an individual service is not sufficient to get environment variable changes to propagate to them, because the services run in a shared (pseudo?) desktop session, which gets its environment upon startup. In my experience you need to reboot a machine to get env var changes to propagate to the service desktop session. Not sure how that would work with Docker.